bazel c++ program which used JNI, how to deal with the path of the .jar with relative path
bazel make a bazel-bin at last, my c++ codes can't find the relative path of jar at last.
options[1].optionString = (char*)"-Djava.class.path=.:JavaNativeInterface.jar"

I try genrule in bazel, but it didn't work.

You specified two paths relative to the current working directory. Not something that Bazel has any control over, I think. How are you installing/invoking your program and how is the jar file built?

I used maven to built a jar, and copy the jar to the file of c++ project src/jni/ with the code which used the jni, and bazel will make a cc_library, which built all .cpp and .h src/ into .so. Need I move the .jar to the bazel-bin with .so?

That is up to you. If you expect to find the jar file in the same directory as the library, you need to write code to find the absolute path of the library and calculate the path to the library from there. Or you could expect the path in an environment variable and read that in your JVM setup. (typically done through a startup script)

Thank you for solving my problem! I finally choose the environment variable way. Export an environment variable at first. The value of it is the path of .jar. And the add --action_env=XXX in .bazelrc. Then, I getenv in progarm.

Suggest you write that as a self-answer so other people can find the answer more easily, especially because it is something specific to Bazel.

I chosed the environment variable way.
In bash script, I used export JNI_JAR=/path/to/myjar.jar to set an environment virable. Of course, I will do something with the 'path' to deal with different situations.
Then, the script will use bazel to build or test my project. So I add --action_env=XXX in .bazelrc.
Finally, I can use getenv("JNI_JAR") to get an absolute path.
